# TypeScript how to overwrite onClick event signature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a sub-component as below

```js
import React from 'react';

interface TodoListProps {
  items: { id: string; text: string }[];
  buttonHandler: (todoId: string) => void;
}

const TodoList: React.FC<TodoListProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.items.map((todo) => (
        <li key={todo.id}>
          <span>{todo.text}</span>
          <button onClick={props.buttonHandler}>CLICK ME</button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Specifying `props.buttonHandler` as a function that expecting `todoId` as parameter, and `buttonHandler` are expected to be passed down from parent. It works great that my parent is getting the type checking correctly.

The problem now is that I'm getting below error at this component

> Type '(todoId: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'todoId' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

How should I handle the problem

Comment: Did you read the error message? The onClick callback will indeed be called with an event object, **not** a string. You should handle it by either: 1. passing down a callback that accepts an event; or 2. wrapping it with something like `{() => props.buttonHandler(todo.id)}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I handle the problem

Pass the correct information to `buttonHandler`. Currently, you're passing it an event, not a string.

There are a couple of ways you could do that, such as a wrapper arrow function:

```
<button onClick={() => props.buttonHandler(todo.id)}>CLICK ME</button>
```